# DigitalOcean - How to get the droplet cpu utilization via API

Tags: digital-ocean

Is there an api to retrieve the droplet's cpu utilisation (not the load metric)? I cannot figure out how to retrieve that information

Comment: I am not sure about an API but a quick searched yielded this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-monitor-cpu-use-on-digitalocean-droplets

Comment: @blurfus yeah i specifically need from the api. sadly that is not helpful

Comment: Understood.  I supposed you could reach out to DOs IT/Help and see if they can point you in the right direction there?  It seems like a product question, not a programming question. Did you already try the CPU metrics API? https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/get_droplet_cpu_metrics